# How to Make Prime Generator Code More Efficient

Tags: scala

As a beginner in Scala, I got a problem in SPOJ:

`Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!`

Input

The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Output

For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

Example

**Input:**
2
1 10
3 5

**Output:**
2
3
5
7

3
5
`
Warning: large Input/Output data, be careful with certain languages (though most should be OK if the algorithm is well designed)

### Run environment and requirement:

Added by:   Adam Dzedzej
Date:   2004-05-01
Time limit: 6s
Source limit:   50000B
Memory limit:   1536MB
Cluster:    Cube (Intel Pentium G860 3GHz)
Languages:  All except: NODEJS PERL 6 SCM chicken

### My code is here:

```scala
import math.sqrt

object Pro_2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // judge whether a Long is a prime or not
    def isPrime(num: Long): Boolean = {
      num match {
        case num if (num < 2) => false
        case _ => {
          2 to (sqrt(num) toInt) forall (num % _ != 0)
        }
      }
    }

    // if a Long is a prime print it in console
    def printIfIsPrime(num: Long) = {
      if (isPrime(num))
        println(num)
    }

    // get range
    def getInput(times: Int) = {
      for (input <- 0 until times) yield {
        val range = readLine().split(" ")
       (range(0) toLong, range(1) toLong)
      }
    }

    val ranges = getInput(readInt())
    for (time <- 0 until ranges.length) {
      (ranges(time)._1 to ranges(time)._2).foreach(printIfIsPrime(_))
      if (time != ranges.length - 1)
        println()
    }

  }
}
```

When I run my code in SPOJ, I got a result: `time limit exceeded`

I need make my code more efficient, could you please help me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isPrime could be written in a lower level style. Also you can increase the speed of the println method.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val out = new java.io.PrintWriter(System.out, false)

  def isPrime(n: Long): Boolean = {
    if(n <= 3) return n > 1
    else if(n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false
    else {
      var i = 5
      while(i*i <= n) {
        if(n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0) return false
        i += 6
      }
      return true
    }
  }

  def printIfIsPrime(num: Long) = {
    if (isPrime(num)) {
      out.println(num)
    }
  }
  ...
  val ranges = getInput(readInt())
  for (time <- 0 until ranges.length) {
    (ranges(time)._1 to ranges(time)._2).foreach(printIfIsPrime(_))
    if (time != ranges.length - 1)
      out.println()
  }
  out.flush()
}
```

Comment: Performance optimisation is to precompute sqrt(n), store in a variable and compare this to i instead of repeatedly squaring new versions of i. i.e val rootN = sqrt(n) and while (i <= rootN)